# Safari not able to set cookie in iframe even when using hasStorageAccess API

Tags: cookies, iframe, safari

I am building a web application and every customer gets it own environment.
The customer should be able to url forward a subdomain to embed my environment.

So for example: myapplication.customerdomain.com should be forwarded to application.mydomain.com

This works but the domain forwarder creates a frame (when cloaking is enabled) with application.mydomain.com.

I need to be able to set cookies in application.mydomain.com but at least safari blocks this.

Even when i use the hasStorageAccess API I can only create cookies if the parent domain (which is not my domain) sets a cookie first.

Is there a workaround?
I don't need to create cookies for the parent (customer) domain, but only for my application.

I have tested other browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox etc) and there it seems to work by default, even in Windows